# Adding function options via kwargs (e.g., verbose)

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm trying to efficiently add optional features so some class functions. Pretty new to python, so I'm trying to learn good habits.  I'm implementing this through `**kwargs` (for better or worse).

One such example is adding a 'verbose' option which adds several conditional print statements throughout the functions, and will suffice as a unit test here. There's a lot of SO Q+As (and other tutorials) about `**kwargs` usage for variables but less about usage as execution flags.

My frame of reference here is thinking in terms of overloads and switch statements so I was on the fence with using a `try` statement if various `**kwargs` existed.

Can't copy and paste, so here's some basic example:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Bowl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = []

    def fill_bowl(self, *fruit, **options):
        self.fruit_list = []
        for x in options:
            if options.get(x) == 'verbose':
                verbose = 1
            else:
                verbose = 0
```

From here, I'd add several `if verbose == 1: print...` various attributes of the `Fruit` I'm adding to the bowl, number of contents, etc., etc. to help with sanity checks without going through the debugger in-depth.

This is functional, barring some transcription error in typing this.  Am I on the right track, or is there a more intuitive way to accomplish this?

Comment: And the point of using `**kwargs` there is what? Why not just add a `verbose=False` parameter?

Comment: You probably want to use the `logging` module, and the verbosity of the logger is something you want to configure when you first start your program, rather than every time you call a particular method.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using kwargs here. This are for when you need to accept unknown options. Here i you know what you want to accept: a verbose parameter. To make it optional you can give it a default value.

```
def fill_bowl(self, *fruit, verbose=0):
```

Although you should probably use True and False rather than 1 and 0.

(And note even if you did want to use kwargs, trees no reason to iterate through the dict like that; you would just do `if kwargs.get("verbose")`.)

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking if various member functions were calling each other, 'verbose' might be a valid option throughout, but other options might not be. To pass these flags downstream in a more flexible manner (and with growth in mind), kwargs seemed viable. Regardless, using a default value probably makes more sense.  Thanks again.